# C program discrepancy - windows 10 - running program in Sublime Text 3 and cmd

Tags: c, cmd, sublimetext3

This is my program -

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hi");
}
```

When I run it through Sublime Text, it shows it properly in the command prompt; but when I try to run it again in cmd, it says:

```
prog1.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
 main()
 ^~~~
```

So I changed the program to -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hi");
}
```

When I run this, same way it runs correctly the first time, but when I run it again, it displays nothing!

[image: This is the output for the first program]

This is the output of the first program.

[image]

This is for the second one.

The 'hi' in the first line of cmd is the output of the program, which runs correctly for the first time.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 3):

`gcc` doesn't "run" your program, it compiles it. The editor is configured to compile *and* run.

You then manually compile, but don't run. You can specify the output name, like:

```sh
gcc -o prog1.exe prog1.c
```

Then run `prog1.exe` if that succeeded. This is where a tool like [`make`](https://makefiletutorial.com) comes in handy to help automate this.

Comment: Can we compile and run the program in cmd? If yes, can you please post the command for that?

Comment: If you're using your editor to compile just use the editor as you usually do.